# Identification as a substructure - injective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Quite often in mathematical literature the following type of statement is made, and the following is only an example:

Let $f\in K[X]$ be a separable polynomial of degree $n>0$ with splitting field $L$ over $K$. If $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in L$ are roots of $f$, then

$\varphi\colon \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\longrightarrow S(\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\})\simeq\mathfrak{S}_n,\\
\sigma\mapsto\sigma|_{\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}}$

defines an injective group homomorphism from the galois group of $L/K$ into the group of permutations of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$, such that we can **identify** $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ as a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

(Excerpt of Siegfried Bosch - "Algebra" 8.ed. p.158)

We shall not worry about the proof here.

The important thing here is the injective homomorphism. More generally, if we have two algebraic structures $A,B$ and we have a structure conserving map $\varphi$ which is injective from $A$ to $B$, we can consider $A$ as a substructure of $B$, whatever this might be (field, group, ring,...).

I don't really know why we can identify $A$ as a substructure of $B$ nor what this even means, since it is not a real substructure. (Note, that I have written 'identify' in bold to emphasize that it is not a subgroup per definition)

Could somebody elaborate on this concept of identification as a substructure by having an injective homomorphism? What is it used for and what exactly is its meaning? It is not a substructure by definition, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are given two structures $A$ and $B$ and an injective homomorphism $f: A \to B$, then, as a notational convenience, we can pretend that $A$ is actually a substructure of $B$, by agreeing that $x$ really means $f(x)$ if $x$ is an element of $A$ and we want an element of $B$. I.e., we use $f$ to identify elements of $A$ with their images in $B$.

A standard example is in the constructions of the number systems $\Bbb{N}$, $\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$. We pretend that the natural number $1$ is an integer and a rational and a real number and a complex number despite the fact that the multiplicative units in the standard constructions of $\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$ are all different.

Comment: The image of a homomorphism would naturally be a substructure of the structure mapping into. What you described as an example is an embedding. For example, we have that an element of the galois group of $L/K$ is a K-homomorphism, but an element of the symmetric group is just a bijective self-map. The elements of the sets are different, whereas we have $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Z}$ and so on. What confuses me, is that the sets might be fundamentally different.

Comment: No. $\Bbb{N}$ is **not** a subset of $\Bbb{Z}$ if you construct $\Bbb{Z}$ from $\Bbb{N}$ in the usual way. As an another example that is perhaps closer to what you have in mind,the symmetric group $S_3$ on $3$ elements can be viewed as the group of isometries of an equilateral triangle, but to do this you have to identify a permutation of the three vertices with an isometric transformation on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Just to be sure: Having an injective homom. means we can identify the images with their preimages, but they are not actual subsets, right?

Comment: That's right. You could actually forcibly make $\Bbb{N}$ a subset of $\Bbb{Z}$ etc. by doing the standard construction and then using what most of us would call $(\Bbb{Z} \setminus \Bbb{N}) \cup \Bbb{N}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}$, but once you have the structures and their defining properties, it doesn't really matter what the elements of the structures are.